# amsart problem with typsetting title

Tags: macros, titles, amsart, expandafter

I tried to implement a metalevel for the author and title commands, because most style files want them to be a little bit different and I want to be able to easily change the style file.

Long story short I observed that the `amsart` class behaves strangely, when I insert a macro into `\title{}`. It does not throw an error, but does not capitalize the title. However it will be still typeset in boldface.

So there is neither no effect nor all effects. I also tried to place `\expandafter` at all places that I could think of, but apparently I don't really understand this command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\newtoks\mytitleA
\mytitleA={This is a title}

\newcommand{\mytitle}{This is a title}
\newcommand{\myauthor}{This is me}

% toggle the following commands to see that only the last version
% produceses the correct layout
%\title{\the\mytitleA}
%\title{\mytitle}
\title{This is a title}

% for the author I cannot spot a difference
\author{\myauthor}
\author{This is me}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Other style files like `article` don't seem to typeset the title differently, if it is nested in a macro, at least I couldn't tell the difference. Hence, maybe there is something wrong with the `amsart` implementation of `\title{}` or `\maketitle`.

Is there a way of fixing this or at least make a nested macro work?

Comment: why are you using a toks register for the title? Ah sorry you tried both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot one that *does* work, namely

```
\expandafter\title\expandafter{\the\mytitleA}
```

Of course nothing avoiding `\the` in front of `\mytitleA` can work, because `\the` is necessary in order to deliver the contents of the `\toks` register.

What's the problem? By default `amsart` just uses `\uppercase` (it shouldn't, but that's another issue).

You can avoid the issue by loading `textcase` that coerces `amsart` into using `\MakeTextUppercase` so full (protected) expansion is made before `\uppercase` does its job.

##### With a `\toks` register

```
\documentclass[a4paper,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{textcase}

\newtoks\mytitleA
\mytitleA={This is a title}
\newcommand{\myauthor}{This is me}

\begin{document}

\title{\the\mytitleA}
\author{\myauthor}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

##### With a command

```
\documentclass[a4paper,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{textcase}

\newcommand{\mytitle}{This is a title}
\newcommand{\myauthor}{This is me}

\begin{document}

\title{\mytitle}
\author{\myauthor}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

##### Output (the same with both examples)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this solves my question. However, I just realized that, if I want to use the optional parameter of `\title[short title]{long title}`, then I don't see how I can generalize this solution.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Neither do I, without knowing what your aim is. Why not simply using the standard syntax?

Comment: I don't see where to put `\expandafter` in `\title[\myshorttitle]{\myshorttitle}` in order to have everything typset "normally".
As I explained in the beginning of my post, I want to implement a metalevel to easily switch between style files. However, I think the solution with `\usepackage{textcase}` will do it.